# Logging command IDs invoked via keybindings in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does VSCode provide any mechanisms to **log** or **display** the command IDs the user invokes as the user works on the editor (in particular the command IDs invoked through keybindings)?

Put another way, I'm looking for a **history** of "**user actions**" invoked, with the  `commandID` and corresponding `when` clause context.

This can be very useful for debugging anything (keybindings, extensions, tasks, etc). E.g. something similar to [this](https://github.com/lewang/command-log-mode) (Emacs) but for VSCode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Command Palette: `Developer: Set Log Level...`
2. Choose `Trace`
3. Choose `Output` in the Terminal, Search, etc.
4. In the dropdown box to the right choose `Log (Window)`
5. or choose `Log (Extension Host)` if that is involved in the command - you get cleaner logs.

---

However, you asked about `when` clause contexts and I don't see them anywhere in the logs.

[image: demo of logging command traces]